# How to make unlocking the phone using the password perform a specfic function?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Okay so I was thinking about this, and I can't seem to get my head around how to do it, so your help will be micy appreciated.

Basically, I have an android phone and my password is a pin that I use to unlock it. My question is, how do I edit the code so that:

1. I can have two seperate passwords,
2. One of the passwords will have a specific function such as deleting an application, so for example

If input is 1234, unlock the phone and uninstall Facebook?

I'm pretty certain this is doable, but I am a programming novice which is why I'm asking the experts! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Xposed module [PIN/Pattern Shortcuts](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.hamzah.pinshortcuts) allows this behaviour. To use, you must:

- Root your phone
- Install [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)
- Install PIN/Pattern Shortcuts module, enable from Xposed app and reboot